# How to enable SCAYT in rte_ckeditor from within TYPO3 8.7

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I am trying to get the ckeditor [Spell Check As You Type plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/scayt) to be enabled by default in TYPO3 8.7.18. Here's the relevant part of the `yaml` file that I thought would make this enabled by default but it's not working.

```
editor:
  config:
    scayt_autoStartup: "true"
```

Here's some additional resources:

- [SCAYT plugin docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_spellcheck.html)
- [A good TYPO3 rte_ckeditor extension tutorial](https://usetypo3.com/ckeditor.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes were used where it should not have been. It should be just `true` with no quotes like this...

```
editor:
  config:
    scayt_autoStartup: true
```